# nginx 403 error while serving static files

Tags: nginx

I was trying to serve static files using nginx server. Here is my server configuration.

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.com;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        root /root/my_name;
        autoindex on;
    }
```

My static files are located in the folder `/root/my_name/static/`
inside the static folder, there is a file called `sample.txt`.

I am getting 403 Forbidden error message while trying to access the static file using the url `www.mydomain.com/static/sample.txt`

Note : I have given `chmod +x static`, to check whether it is some problem with permission. Still no success.

Comment: Check file mode of your `sample.txt`, do you have any read permission?

Comment: @YinGang I have executed `chmod +x static` and `chmod +r /static/sample.txt` . But still getting the same error.

Comment: Using linux? Why not check `/var/log/nginx/error.log`?

Comment: Thanks @YinGang , I checked the error log. It was due to permission error. I moved the static folder to `/opt`. Then it worked fine. Do you have any idea why nginx cannot serve static files at another location like `/root/my_name/static/` , is there any permission error for nginx to access from another location?

Comment: /root/ is normally not readable buy anyone, but root itself

Comment: Anyway, it was a bad idea to put web files to root's home